# capture all the browser URL in Webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to print all the browser url navigated during a test in webdriver.
For eg. :- the reference site is m.rechargeitnow.com and i made a transaction failure. Now the task is  to capture all the browser url navigated during a complete transaction.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to build a list as you perform each step. Something like:

```
urls = []
urls.append(driver.current_url) /starting URL
/do step one
urls.append(driver.current_url) /URL following step 1
/do step two
urls.append(driver.current_url) /URL following step 2
/do all steps
print(urls)
```

If you only want to see that list of urls in the case of a test-fail or test-error, use a `try` block.

Comment: I would just create a test class Class(unittest.TestCase). setUp() method - create the empty list. In tearDown() - print it

Comment: That's also a good alternative - he seems to suggest that he only wants to see it during a test fail. Really depends what he wants with that list of URLs I guess.